# PHP SQL Server Connection working or not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli

```
$serverName = 'servername';   
$uid = 'username';     
$pwd = 'password'; 


$conn = new mysqli($serverName, $uid, $pwd );    
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Connection failed: " ;
}
else
{
echo "Connected successfully";
}
```

This is my code. It gets connected to the database. I just want to confirm the code is right, because when i try doing this

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

it throws me connection failed error.
So, is my code connected to the server or not? because when i run a query it does not show me anything.

Code for the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT max([line_nbr]) FROM [dbo].[so_audit]";

$res = $conn->query($sql);
var_dump($res);
```

please advise

Comment: Are you using sql-server? `when i run a query it does not show me anything` Please add code showing the query execution.

Comment: So what is in `$conn->connect_error`?

Comment: @user3783243 yes, i am using sqlserver

Comment: @AlexHowansky I don't get the question you are asking. $conn->connect_error is when the server is not connected.

Comment: Okay, then you can't use `new mysqli`. Use PDO.

Comment: You said, "it throws me connection failed error." What is it printing?

Comment: @user3783243 Can you show me how? like what exactly to write. I am really new at this.

Comment: @AlexHowansky No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: @user3783243 Error: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server does not support connections to SQL Server 2000 or earlier versions.

Comment: `SQL Server 2000`?? How old is the DB you are interacting with?

Comment: @user3783243 Yes, it is 2000 and i have my latest driver and latest php version

Answer (score 0):

you are not trying to connect to sql server u should use sqlsrv_connect instead of mysqli
so u need to specify the server name and an array containin connection info for that your code should look like this :

```
 $srv ="servername"
    $info=array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $srv, $info);
    if (!$conn) {
        echo "Connection failed: " ;
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Connected successfully";
    }
```

Comment: 500 error. not working

Comment: did you added sql server extensions and installed ODBC driver ??

Comment: and please put this on your first line so you can get the error instead of 500 :

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Comment: Again throwing a 500 error. and i added sql server extensions and driver as well

Comment: can you please tell me what web server are you using ??

Comment: it is my company's server.